# Wheel building failed for phik, while installing pandas-profiling

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pandas-profiling

I tried appending my issue to a pre-existing query on the same topic opened up yesterday, but I was not able to comment, and thus ended up making a new question.
I tried installing wheel and phik individually, but kept getting the same error, as shown below.
I am running Windows 11, is it possible that this is causing the problem?
All help is appreciated.
*Edit : Rolled back to Windows 10 today, but still ending up with the same error.

```
Building wheel for phik (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [118 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\betainc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\binning.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\bivariate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\data_quality.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\definitions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\entry_points.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\outliers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\phik.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\report.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\resources.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\significance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\simulation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\statistics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      copying phik\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\decorators
      copying phik\decorators\pandas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\decorators
      copying phik\decorators\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\decorators
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      copying phik\simcore\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      running egg_info
      writing phik.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to phik.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to phik.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to phik.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to phik.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'phik.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[cod]' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tests'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py' found under directory 'tests'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'NOTICE'
      writing manifest file 'phik.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying phik\simcore\CMakeLists.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      copying phik\simcore\asa159.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      copying phik\simcore\asa159.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      copying phik\simcore\bindings.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      copying phik\simcore\simulation.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\simcore
      running build_ext
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT):
        Generator

          NMake Makefiles

        does not support platform specification, but platform

          x64

        was specified.


      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/girin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-88sig9ez/phik_e11a8869041b47f1a81e58f863225cc2/build/temp.win-amd64-3.10/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 244, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 229, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 265, in <module>
          setup(ext_modules=EXTERNAL_MODULES, **setup_args)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "setup.py", line 159, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(
        File "C:\Users\girin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\girin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sig9ez\\phik_e11a8869041b47f1a81e58f863225cc2', '-Dpybind11_DIR=C:\\Users\\girin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-dncee5_0\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\pybind11\\share\\cmake\\pybind11', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\girin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sig9ez\\phik_e11a8869041b47f1a81e58f863225cc2\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10\\phik\\lib', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\girin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-DPHIK_VERSION_INFO=0.12.0', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-A', 'x64', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\girin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sig9ez\\phik_e11a8869041b47f1a81e58f863225cc2\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10\\phik\\lib']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for phik
Failed to build phik
ERROR: Could not build wheels for phik, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with phik and I've installed the version required for pandas-profiling with this : !pip install phik==0.11.1 and it solved the problem.